# Change unity input to crossplatform input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cross-platform

This is the code i have coded through the online tutorial it is a normal swiping input but i want to change it to cross-platform input. I have no idea how to change it hope you guys can help me out

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
{
    if (isSwipping)
    {
        Vector2 diff = Input.GetTouch(0).position - startingTouch;
        diff = new Vector2(diff.x / Screen.width, diff.y / 
        Screen.width);

        if (diff.magnitude > 0.01f)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(diff.y) > Mathf.Abs(diff.x))
            {
                if (diff.y < 0)
                {
                    Slide();
                }
                else
                {
                    Jump();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (diff.x < 0)
                {
                    ChangeLane(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    ChangeLane(1);
                }
            }

            isSwipping = false;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        startingTouch = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        isSwipping = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        isSwipping = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there are no unified ways to address swipe across all platforms, including windows. but you can come up with your own wrapper for android/ios. see this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-swipe-and-tap-mobile-input.376160/ and this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/released-easy-swipe-touch-controller-android-ios-unity-4-5-playmaker-support.316418/

Comment: Thanks for your help :)